# C++ usage of non-template (but type specific) function inside of template class

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I got the situation that I got a generic library that is used in a lot of projects.
This library just contains a quite simple template class (inside of template_class.h). The template class then will be used in multiple executables (represented by main.cpp).
The main.cpp additionally has access to some autogenerated function in autogenerated.h.
As the name suggests, the functions in autogenerated.h are autogenerated and cannot be modified.
This "scaleFct" implementations should be used within the template function.
My Intention is to keep the template_class independent from the concrete usage.

The question now is how to make the autogenerated functions accessible for usage within the template. Might forward declarations be an option? or do I need to pass the function pointer as a template argument?

Here a minimal (not-working) example:
(as far as I remember, this sample even worked in VC++ - however right now I only got access to gcc 7 and there it is giving me an error message: "‘scaleFct’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation "

Thanks much in advance

```
// template_class.h

#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Aggregator
{
  T sum_ = 0;

 public:

  T aggregate(T value){
    sum_ += scaleFct(value);
    return sum_;
  }
};
```

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "template_class.h"
#include "autogenerated.h"

int main() {
  Aggregator<float> aggregator;

  std::cout << "current sum: " << aggregator.aggregate(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "current sum: " << aggregator.aggregate(1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
// autogenerated.h
#pragma once

float scaleFct(float val) {return val*2;}
double scaleFct(double val) {return val*2;}
```

Comment: Why not include autogenerated.h in template_class.h? Seems like that what you really want, but for some reason you want to do it in some other way.

Comment: If that's not possible, at least you can change the order of inclusion in main.cpp

Comment: ah ok
maybe I missed a bit of information: The autogenerated file is a different one for every executable. So in fact I got a lot of different ones for all kinds of Template Arguments. And the List of possible template arguments unfortunately also is growing

Comment: Thanks: the order of inclusion seems to have solved the problem.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function inside a template class, lookup proceeds roughly like this:

1. Can I see it in the current class I am in (not including parents)?
2. Can I see it in parents whose type is not dependent on my template parameters?
3. Can I find it at the point where the template is declared?

All of this happens before template arguments are substituted in.  This is done at the point of declaration, not instantiation.

Once you pass the types in, another lookup is done:

4. Can I find it via argument dependent lookup on the template-argument dependent arguments of the function?

This is done at the points of instantiation.  A note that if two different points of actual instantiation (which, I think, includes the end of the translation unit where instantiations occur) result in a different lookup result, your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

In earlier versions of MSVC, 1 2 and 3 was delayed until the point of instantiation, and it also looked into base classes whose types where dependent on template arguments.  So your code worked.

Every modern compiler uses basically the above steps (I may have made a few minor errors, if you need to know exactly what happens, look into it further; but the above should give you the gist).

You'll see at the point of declaration, `scaleFct` is not visible, so it isn't found.  And argument dependent lookup doesn't occur on primitive types, so step 4 doesn't find it either.

The easiest/best way to fix your problem is to `#include "autogenerated.h"` in `template_class.h`.

Another, not as good, option is to `#include "autogenerated.h"` before `#include "template_class.h"`.  That sucks; you generally don't want a header file to only work if included in a specific order in C++, it makes your code base very fragile.

Another option is to wrap `template_class.h` in a header that includes autogenerated then template class headers.

Another option is to add forward declarations of `scaleFct` to `template_class.h`, possibly by putting them into a `forward_declare_autogenerated.h` header file.

Another option is to add a trampoline to `Aggregator`.

```
template<typename T, class Trampoline>
class Aggregator
{
  T sum_ = 0;

public:

  T aggregate(T value){
    sum_ += Trampoline::scaleFct(value);
    return sum_;
  };
};
```

then write up a class `Trampoline` with `static` members that direct `scaleFct` to the right operation.

Another option is a traits class.

```
template<class T>
struct Traits {
  static T scaleFct(T in){ return ::scaleFct(in); }
};
template<typename T, typename Trampoline=Traits<T>>
class Aggregator
{
  T sum_ = 0;

public:

  T aggregate(T value){
    sum_ += Trampoline::scaleFct(value);
    return sum_;
  };
};
```

which you specialize for each `T` and inject the calls to the autogenerated code in.  You can also pass in an explicit Trampoline here.

Another approach is tag dispatching.

```
namespace adl {
  template<class T>
  struct tag_t {};
  template<class T>
  constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
}

template<typename T>
class Aggregator
{
  T sum_ = 0;

public:

  T aggregate(T value){
    sum_ += scaleFct(adl::tag<T>, value);
    return sum_;
  };
};
```

then adding

```
namespace adl {
  inline float scaleFct(tag_t<float>, float f) { return ::scaleFct(f); }
}
```

before doing `Aggregator<float>` will find that function via ADL.

Comment: Does anyone else look at "trampoline" and think it is spelled wrong even when it isn't?